# How to write SQL JOIN query with geolocation in php

Tags: mysql

I am new to sql.

Sample of **offerings** Table

`offering_id  |  offering_meal_id  |  offering_name  |  offering_profile_id | Offering_Expiration_Date_Time |  Lat  |  Lon`

Sample of **profile** Table

`profile_id  |  fullname`

I am passing following parameters `$latitude` , `$longitude`, `$meal_id`
I want to write a query which will

1. get all data from `offerings` table in basis of latitude and longitude and `Offering_Expiration_Date_Time` is greater than or equal to today's date. For this I have following calculation which is working.

   ```
      SELECT *, ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( ".$latitude." ) ) *
      COS( RADIANS(  Lat ) ) * COS( RADIANS(  Lon ) - RADIANS( ".$longitude." ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( ".$latitude." ) ) 
     * SIN( RADIANS(  Lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM offerings  HAVING distance < 3 AND Offering_Expiration_Date_Time>='".date('Y-m-d h:i:s')."'
   ```
2. Next Select only those offering which `meal_id = $meal_id`
3. Join `profile` table and get `fullname` from it where `offerings.offering_profile_id = profile.profile_id`
4. order it by `offering_id`

**EDIT**

```
SELECT offerings.*,profile.fullname, 
( 6371 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( 16.691120 ) ) * COS( RADIANS( Lat ) ) * COS( RADIANS( Lon ) - RADIANS( 74.219978 ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( 16.691120 ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( Lat ) ) ) ) 
AS distance
FROM offerings 
INNER JOIN profile
ON offerings.offering_profille_id = profile.profile_id
WHERE distance < 3 
AND offerings.offering_meal_id = 2
AND Offering_Expiration_Date_Time>='2017-08-23 15:43:00' 
ORDER BY offerings.offering_id 
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your having clause, join to the profile table like so:

Inner join profile on offerings.offering_profile_id = profile.profile_id

Then include at end:

Order by offerings.offering_id

Also make sure to include in your select statement
Profile.fullname

Also change having to where and add this into your where condition:
And offerings.offering_meal_id = $meal_id

Comment: Please check my edit Its giving following error in SQL  `#1052 - Column 'Lat' in field list is ambiguous `

Comment: Well it is working Thankyou Anthony Just one more problem on `distance` `#1054 - Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Made it offerings.Lat

Comment: one way to fix the distance error is to take out  distance < 3.  Then do this:  select * from (   [your existing sql]  )  where distance < 3                                    The reason for your error is that distance is not a concrete column to use in the where clause because it is dynamically calculated.  So to use the distance where clause, it needs to be outside of that query.